# Subtracting one pandas datetime column from another with some identical values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subtract two datetime columns from each other to get the seconds difference, but my problem is that some of the columns are identical to each other, and so when they are subtracted I'm hitting the boundary seconds at 86399.  What I want to display is 0.  Some of the items subtract correctly because they are different values. The line of code I have is below, with two example datetimes like so:

```
2018-08-01 00:04:30 2018-08-01 00:04:30
2018-08-01 00:26:32 2018-08-01 00:27:30


df['sessiontime'] = (df['logofftime'] - df['logontime']).dt.seconds
```

I'm assuming the answer is simple, but I was trying to use a .where method but the pandas documentation says that that method is deprecated.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using pandas 0.23.3 and python 3.6.6.

Comment: would you like show us the warning message ?

Comment: I don't get a warning message.  The output just isn't what I expect.  I though it would be 0 but it is 86399.

Comment: It work fine on my side

Comment: Interesting.  I must not be seeing something on my side.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was pulling in my logofftime from my original SQL query incorrectly, and the logofftime was actually earlier than the logontime and thus it thought it was essentially a full year difference.  I was relying on output to an excel file that wasn't displaying ms correctly.